How to handle situation where avro formatter records are in DL topic - get Schema not found; error code: 40403
I have messages that went to a DL topic.  The topic they normally go to is the "attempts" topic, but the sink connector had an issue so they failed over to a dead letter topic.
Error: Error retrieving Avro key schema version for id 206
....
.RestClientException: Schema not found; error code: 40403
I have created another connector to read those messages in the DL topic and sink them to ClickHouse.  The issue though is that the connector can not find the avro schema id that is in the message.  The schema is named based on the attempts topic, but since the messages are in the dl topic the connector is having issue with finding that schema id.
I've tried several configs on the connector but nothing seems to work.  Even recreated the key and value schemas with the dl topic name, but that didn't work either.
How can I resolve this?

I think you'll need to lookup id 206 (or all versions of the attempts topic) in the registry then manually register them to the  subject name of the DLQ topic

@OneCricketeer yes that worked.  Initially I thought I could specify some settings on the connector but I couldn't get that to work.
Curl to do it if any one is wondering...
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" 
--data "{"schema": $(curl -s https:///subjects/-key/versions/latest | jq '.schema')}" 
https:///subjects/<NEW_SUBJECT_NAME>-key/versions
